# Не создается таблица и данные H2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, h2

Работаю с `spring-boot` и `h2`. Не могу понять, в чем проблема, делаю все по туториалу. Перепробовал различные варианты. Таблица создается, но где и каким образом, - не совсем ясно. `Spring`, по идее, должен сам все конфигурировать. Но я пытался задать конфигурацию и вручную.

В `Gradle` повесил две зависимости:

```
testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'

runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
```

Конфигурация:

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.dataSource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
#spring.dataSource.username=sa
#spring.dataSource.password=            
spring.h2.console.enabled=true    
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug    
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

В папке `resources` два файла. `data.sql`

```
CREATE TABLE number_entity(
  name VARCHAR (30),
  value INTEGER (10)
);
```

и `schema.sql`

```
INSERT INTO number_entity
VALUES ('test1', 2);

INSERT INTO number_entity
VALUES ('test2', 3);
```

При запуске проекта создается таблица. Лог:

```
Hibernate: 
    drop table number_entity if exists

Hibernate: 
    create table number_entity (
       name varchar(255) not null,
        value integer,
        primary key (name)
    )
```

Но не более того. `data.sql` как будто не отрабатывает.

Сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "number_entity")
public class NumberEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private int value;

    // constructors, getters and setters //
}
```

Подключаюсь через `localhost:8080/h2-console`

[image: h2_stack]

И там ничего, пусто. В `IntellJ IDEA` тоже, только БД `testdb` и схема public.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Проверял это решение в `spring-wevmvc`, но думаю, что в `spring-boot` тоже будет работать.</sub>

---

См. [H2 Documentation](https://h2database.com/javadoc/index.html) - есть средство специальное для запуска скриптов: [RunScript](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/RunScript.html). При инициализации `dataSource` можно добавить создание и заполнение таблиц следующим образом:

**application.properties**: указываем путь к файлу со скриптом

```
datasource.driverClass=org.h2.Driver
datasource.user=sa
datasource.password=
datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:users;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
datasource.script=classpath:resources/users.sql
```

**WebAppConfig.java**: зачитываем файл в объект [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

```java
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${datasource.driverClass}") String driverClassName,
        @Value("${datasource.user}") String username,
        @Value("${datasource.password}") String password,
        @Value("${datasource.url}") String url,
        @Value("${datasource.script}") Resource script)
        throws SQLException, IOException {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(url);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    // создаём и заполняем таблицы
    createTables(url, username, password, script);

    return dataSource;
}
```

Открываем [`JdbcConnection`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcConnection.html), тоже из набора `h2`, и выполняем скрипт:

```java
private void createTables(String url, String username,
                          String password, Resource script)
        throws SQLException, IOException {

    Properties info = new Properties();
    info.put("user", username);
    info.put("password", password);

    JdbcConnection connection = new JdbcConnection(url, info);
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(script.getInputStream());

    RunScript.execute(connection, reader);

    reader.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

**users.sql**: создаём и заполняем таблицы

```sql
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nickname    varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    first_name  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    second_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    third_name  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT
INTO users(id, nickname, first_name, second_name, third_name)
VALUES (1, 'john', 'Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович');
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Проверял это решение в `spring-wevmvc`, но думаю, что в `spring-boot` тоже будет работать.</sub>

---

В `spring-jdbc` есть конструктор встраиваемых баз данных: [EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html), которому при создании БД можно указать скрипты для создания и заполнения таблиц следующим образом:

**application.properties**: указываем путь к файлу со скриптом и имя базы данных

```ini
datasource.dbname=users
datasource.script=classpath:resources/users.sql
```

**WebAppConfig.java:** создаём базу данных и подключаем дополнительно [`web server`](https://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#createWebServer_String...)

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${datasource.dbname}") String dbname,
        @Value("${datasource.script}") String script) {

    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName(dbname)
            .addScript(script)
            .build();
}

@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createWebServer(); // порт по умолчанию 8082
}
```

**users.sql**: создаём и заполняем таблицы

```sql
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nickname    varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    first_name  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    second_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    third_name  varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT
INTO users(id, nickname, first_name, second_name, third_name)
VALUES (1, 'john', 'Иванов', 'Иван', 'Иванович');
```

---

**Тест:** открываем `http://localhost:8082/` и подключаемся к базе `jdbc:h2:mem:users`

[image: login.jsp]

[image: login.do]

Answer (score 0):

Ты практически все верно сделал!
Убедись, что файл data.sql находиться: `src/main/resources/data.sql`.
И в application.properties раскомменть свойства spring к подключению к БД H2:

`application.properties`:

```
# JPA
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

# Property for enabling the H2 console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

# Connection to H2 database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:todo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

`data.sql`:

```sql
insert into to_do (id,completed,created,description,modified)
values
('8a8080a365481fb00165481fbca90000', true, '2018-08- 
 17T07:42:44.136',
 'Read a Book', '2018-08-17T07:42:44.137'),
('ebcf1850563c4de3b56813a52a95e930', false, '2018-08- 
 17T09:50:10.126', 'Buy Movie Tickets', '2018-08- 
 17T09:50:10.126'),
('78269087206d472c894f3075031d8d6b', false, '2018-08- 
  17T07:42:44.136', 'Clean my Room', '2018-08-17T07:42:44.137');
```

Порт я использовал по умолчанию 8080, поэтому после пуска и компиляции кода, набери в браузере: http://localhost:8080/h2-console

[image: h2-console]

Еще рекомендую прочесть статейки:
https://for-each.dev/lessons/b/-spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql и
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Comment: @insolor понял, исправил)